# How can I create a list from two dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, google-app-engine, dictionary, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to write to a model in the GAE datastore that will have three fields: date, integer, integer.

```
class fusSent(db.Model):
    """ Models a list of the follow-ups due and follow-ups sent """
    date_created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    fu_date = db.DateProperty()
    fus_due = db.IntegerProperty()
    fus_sent = db.IntegerProperty()
```

This data is coming from two different dictionaries which have matching keys (dates). See below.

```
fus_d = {2013-01-01: 1, 2013-04-01: 1, 2013-02-01: 1, 2013-03-01: 1}
fus_s = {2013-01-01: 0, 2013-04-01: 0, 2013-02-01: 1, 2013-03-01: 1}
```

My guess is that I need to combine the dictionaries into a list (like the one below) in order to save it to the datastore. However, I'm not completely sure this is the best approach.

```
fu_list = [(2013-01-01, 1, 0), (2013-04-01, 1, 0), (2013-02-01, 1, 1), (2013-03-01, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Are fus_due and fus_sent just true/false flags?  Use db.BooleanProperty() instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope `fus_d` and `fus_s` dictionaries actually have dates, because your example of `2013-01-01` is actually a math expression that evals to `2011`.  But the following should work

```
s = set(fus_d.keys())
s.update(fus_s.keys())
fu_list = [(k, fus_d.get(k), fus_s.get(k)) for k in s]
```

---

Edit: Also with python 2.7 you can use the `viewkeys` directly from the dict instead of using a `set`.

```
fu_list = [(k, fus_d.get(k), fus_s.get(k)) for k in fus_d.viewkeys() | fus_s]
```

Comment: They do have dates. I just wrote it that way for expedience. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Improving @cmd answer.

In order to write to the database, you should construct a list of model instances and call `db.put` to save them into the database, like this:

```
fus_d = {'2013-01-01': 1, '2013-04-01': 1, '2013-02-01': 1, '2013-03-01': 1}
fus_s = {'2013-01-01': 0, '2013-04-01': 0, '2013-02-01': 1, '2013-03-01': 1}

s = set(fus_d.keys())
s.update(fus_s.keys())
fu_list = [fusSent(fu_date=k, fus_due=fus_d.get(k, 0), fus_sent=fus_s.get(k, 0)) for k in s]
db.put(fu_list)
```

Comment: @655321 while cmd answer is correct regarding the list.. this answer is actually inserting the values in an efficient way right into the datastore...

Answer (score 1):

@cmd has the code to generate the list you requested, but that won't get it into the datastore.  This code will create entities and save them:

```
s = set(fus_d.keys())
s.update(fus_s.keys())
for k in s:
    sent = fusSent(fu_date=k, fus_due=fus_d.get(k), fus_sent=fus_s.get(k))
    sent.put()
```

Comment: I agree, db.put(list) is more efficient.